# How to get the current foreground and background colors of any row in the ttk.Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

There is way to set the color for any row in ttk.Treeeview, but it seems that no method found to get the current colors, foreground color and background color, for any row in the ttk.Treeview.

In following code, No colors settings or with color settings, method `tag_configure` can check the settings for the tags, but not the **current** colors of rows. Also check the method `item`, and it don't return the setting of colors. The same result by using **Style**.

Of course, I can know what colors they are if I set all of them, but how to get the colors if not.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def check():
    for i in range(10):
        print(treeview.tag_configure(i))

root = tk.Tk()

columns = ['Col #1', 'Col #2', 'Col #3']
treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns)
treeview.pack()

for i in range(10):
    treeview.insert('', 'end', iid=i, text=f'Line {i}', values=[1,2,3], tags=(i,))
treeview.heading("#0", text="Col #0")

for col in columns:
    treeview.heading(col, text=col)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Check", command=check)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

No matter rows 3~7 selected or not, it always got empty string returned.

```py
{'text': '', 'image': '', 'anchor': '', 'background': '', 'foreground': '', 'font': ''}
{'text': '', 'image': '', 'anchor': '', 'background': '', 'foreground': '', 'font': ''}
{'text': '', 'image': '', 'anchor': '', 'background': '', 'foreground': '', 'font': ''}
{'text': '', 'image': '', 'anchor': '', 'background': '', 'foreground': '', 'font': ''}
{'text': '', 'image': '', 'anchor': '', 'background': '', 'foreground': '', 'font': ''}
{'text': '', 'image': '', 'anchor': '', 'background': '', 'foreground': '', 'font': ''}
{'text': '', 'image': '', 'anchor': '', 'background': '', 'foreground': '', 'font': ''}
{'text': '', 'image': '', 'anchor': '', 'background': '', 'foreground': '', 'font': ''}
{'text': '', 'image': '', 'anchor': '', 'background': '', 'foreground': '', 'font': ''}
{'text': '', 'image': '', 'anchor': '', 'background': '', 'foreground': '', 'font': ''}
```

[image]